# Is there a way to give Ghost static pages access to the 'posts' variable that index.hbs is passed?

Tags: node.js, ghost-blog

I'm looking to use [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) to host both a blog and a static website, so the structure might look something like this:

- `/`: the landing page (**not** the blog landing page, **doesn't** need access to `posts`)
- `/blog/`: the blog landing page (needs access to `posts` that `index.hbs` typically has access to)
- `/page1/`, etc: static pages which will use `page.hbs` or `page-page1.hbs` as needed
- `/blog-post-whatever`/, etc: blog posts which will use `post.hbs`

The only thing I foresee being an issue is that **only** `index.hbs` (as far as I know) is passed the `posts` template variable (see [code on GitHub here](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/server/controllers/frontend.js#L85)).

Before I go submit a pull request, it'd be nice to know whether:

1. Is there an existing way to get access to the `posts` variable in `page.hbs`?
2. If not, is it worthwhile to submit a pull request for this?
3. If yes, would we really want to send `posts` to *all* the pages? or should the pull request split apart `page.hbs` and only send it to those? or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind hacking the Ghost core files then here is how you can do it for the current version of Ghost (0.7.4). This hack will require recreation if upgrading to a new Ghost version.

First create the template files (that will not change if you upgrade):

Create the home page template in:

**contents/themes/theme-name/home.hbs**

**home.hbs** now supersedes **index.hbs** and will be rendered instead of it.

Also create the blog template file in:

**contents/themes/theme-name/blog.hbs**

The handlebars element that adds the paged posts is

```
{{> "loop"}}
```

so this should be in the **blog.hbs** file.

Again, the above files do not change if you upgrade to a new version of Ghost.

Now edit the following files in the `core/server` directory:

> I have added a few lines before and after the sections of code that you need to add so that you can more easily find the location of where the new code needs to be added.

**/core/server/routes/frontend.js:**

Before:

```
indexRouter.route('/').get(frontend.index);
indexRouter.route('/' + routeKeywords.page + '/:page/').get(frontend.index);
```

After:

```
indexRouter.route('/').get(frontend.index);
indexRouter.route('/blog/').get(frontend.blog);
indexRouter.route('/' + routeKeywords.page + '/:page/').get(frontend.index);
```

This calls the Frontend controller that will render the blog page with the same data level as ‘index’ and ‘home’ (the default is load a the first page of the recent posts) thus enabling us to use the “loop” in the /blog/ page.

**/core/server/controllers/frontend/index.js**

Before:

```
frontendControllers = {
    index: renderChannel('index'),
    tag: renderChannel('tag'),
```

After:

```
frontendControllers = {
    index: renderChannel('index'),
    blog: renderChannel('blog'),
    tag: renderChannel('tag'),
```

**/core/server/controllers/frontend/channel-config.js**

Before:

```
getConfig = function getConfig(name) {
    var defaults = {
        index: {
            name: 'index',
            route: '/',
            frontPageTemplate: 'home'
        },
        tag: {
```

After:

```
getConfig = function getConfig(name) {
    var defaults = {
        index: {
            name: 'index',
            route: '/',
            frontPageTemplate: 'home'
        },
        blog: {
            name: 'blog',
            route: '/blog/',
            frontPageTemplate: 'blog'
        },
        tag: {
```

**/core/server/controllers/frontend/channel-config.js**
Before:

```
indexPattern = new RegExp('^\\/' + config.routeKeywords.page + '\\/'),
rssPattern = new RegExp('^\\/rss\\/'),
homePattern = new RegExp('^\\/$');
```

After:

```
indexPattern = new RegExp('^\\/' + config.routeKeywords.page + '\\/'),
rssPattern = new RegExp('^\\/rss\\/'),
blogPattern = new RegExp('^\\/blog\\/'),
homePattern = new RegExp('^\\/$');
```

and

Before:

```
 if (indexPattern.test(res.locals.relativeUrl)) {
        res.locals.context.push('index');
    } else if (homePattern.test(res.locals.relativeUrl)) {
        res.locals.context.push('home');
        res.locals.context.push('index');
    } else if (rssPattern.test(res.locals.relativeUrl)) {
        res.locals.context.push('rss');
    } else if (privatePattern.test(res.locals.relativeUrl)) {
        res.locals.context.push('private');
```

After:

```
 if (indexPattern.test(res.locals.relativeUrl)) {
        res.locals.context.push('index');
    } else if (homePattern.test(res.locals.relativeUrl)) {
        res.locals.context.push('home');
        res.locals.context.push('index');
    } else if (blogPattern.test(res.locals.relativeUrl)) {
        res.locals.context.push('blog');
    } else if (rssPattern.test(res.locals.relativeUrl)) {
        res.locals.context.push('rss');
    } else if (privatePattern.test(res.locals.relativeUrl)) {
        res.locals.context.push('private');
```

Restart the server and you should see the new /blog/ page come up with the list of recent blog posts

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that I am currently using. I have an off-canvas nav that I want to use to display links to my latest `posts`. On the home page, this works great: I iterate over `posts` and render some links. On the other pages, I don't have the `posts` variable at my disposal.

My solution is this: wrap the pertinent post links on the homepage in a div with an id of "posts", then I make an ajax request for that specific content (using jQuery's load) and inject it into my nav on all other pages except the home page. Here's a link to [jQuery's load docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

#### Code:

**index.hbs**

```
<div id='posts'>
  {{#foreach posts}}
    <li>
      <a href="{{url}}">{{{title}}}</a>
    </li>
  {{/foreach}}
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var $latest = $('#posts');

if ( location.pathname !== '/' )
  $latest.load('/ #posts li');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way currently (Ghost v0.5.8) to access `posts` within a page template.

I would think its probably not worth submitting the pull request. The Ghost devs seem to have their own plans for this and keep saying they'll get around to this functionality. Hopefully its soon because it is basic functionality.

The best way to go about this would be to hack the core yourself. Eventually the better way to do this would be with a hook. It looks like the Ghost API will eventually open up to the point where you can hook into core functions for plugins pretty much the same way Wordpress does it. https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Apps-Getting-Started-for-Ghost-Devs

If this is a theme others will be using I would recommend working within the current limitations of Ghost. It's super annoying, I know, but in the long run its best for your users and your reputation.

If this is **only** for you, then I would hack the core to expose a list of posts or pages as locals in each route. If you're familiar with Express then this shouldn't be very difficult.

I think the way you've done it is pretty creative and there's a part of me that likes it but it really is a seriously ugly hack. If you find yourself hacking these kinds of solutions together a lot then Ghost might not be the tool you want to be using.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution than briangonzalez one, is to get the posts-info from the RSS-feed, instead of the home page.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jack0088/9fd1296be39b975cbb17) for how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the ghost-url-api, it's currently in beta but you can activate it in the administration (Settings > labs).

For example the {{#get}} helper can be use like this in a static page:

```
{{#get "posts" limit="3" include="author,tags"}}
 {{#foreach posts}}
    ... call the loop
 {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

More informations :
http://themes.ghost.org/docs/ghost-url-api

Answer (score 0):

As of Ghost v0.9.0, the Channels API is still under development. However, achieving this is much simpler now. It still requires modification of core files, but I'm planning on submitting some pull requests soon. Currently, one downside of the following method is that your `sitemap-pages.xml` will not contain the `/blog/` URL.

Thanks to [@Yuval's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34543046/764945) for kicking this off.

---

Create a template file for your index page with the path `content/themes/theme-name/index.hbs`. This can contain whatever you would like for your "static" homepage.

---

Create a template file for your blog index page with the path `content/themes/theme-name/blog.hbs`. This simply needs to contain:

```
{{> "loop"}}
```

---

In `/core/server/controllers/frontend/channel-config.js`:

Edit the `var defaults` object to include:

```
blog: {
  name: 'blog',
  route: '/blog/'
}
```